# Can I split a text by chapters without chapter names?

Tags: r, text, split, stringr

I have a `data.frame` with a ID column and a column with a text.

This text is divided by chapters, but each observation has it own chapters.

One pattern I identified is the latin numerals before (like I, II, ...), uppercase letters and is followed by "art" or "Art".

Example:

```r
structure(list(ID = c("56456", "1234564565921"), text = c("TÍTULO II

OBJETIVOS

Art. 2  A Cooperativa terá por objetivo a educação cooperativista e financeira dos seus associados, através da ajuda mútua, da economia sistemática e do uso adequado do crédito. Procurará, ainda, e por todos os meios, fomentar a expansão do Cooperativismo de economia e crédito mútuo.

¶ Único Em todos os aspectos de suas atividades, serão rigorosamente observados os princípios de neutralidade política e indiscriminação religiosa, racial e social.
|
TÍTULO III

DAS ASSEMBLÉIAS GERAIS

Art. 3  O número de associados será ilimitado, mas não poderá ser inferior a 20 (vinte).
|
Art. 4  Poderão associar-se à Cooperativa todos aqueles que, tendo livre disposição de pessoas e bens, concordem com o presente Estatuto, preencham as condições nele estabelecida e sejam empregados dahuiljl S/A, citada no Art. 1, letra C.

TÍTULO IV
DO CAPITAL SOCIAL
Art. 21 – Texto grande aqui para parecer que tem coisa, deveria ter pego algo de outro lugar para dar esse exemplo", 
"IV 
DO CAPITAL SOCIAL
Art. 21 – O Capital Social é ilimitado quanto ao máximo e variável, conforme o número de quotas-partes subscritas, não podendo, porém, o valor ser inferior à R$ 5.000,00 (cinco mil reais).
Parágrafo 1º – O Capital Social é dividido em quotas-partes de R$ 1,00(um real) cada uma, integralizável em duas parcelas de 50% (cinqüenta por cento) cada, em moeda corrente nacional, a primeira no ato da subscrição e a segunda em até um ano após a primeira.
Parágrafo 2º – O associado ao ingressar na cooperativa se obriga a subscrever, 300 (trezentas) quotas-partes.


 V DAS ASSEMBLÉIAS GERAIS
Art. 22 – A Assembléia Geral dos associados é o órgão supremo da Cooperativa, e dentro dos limites da lei e deste estatuto, tomará toda e qualquer decisão de interesse da sociedade, e suas deliberações vinculam a todos, ainda que ausentes ou discordantes.
Art. 23 – A Assembléia Geral será normalmente convocada e dirigida pelo Presidente da Cooperativa.
Parágrafo 1º - Poderá, também, ser convocada pelo Conselho de Administração ou pelo Conselho Fiscal, se ocorrerem motivos graves ou urgentes, ou por 1/5 (um quinto) dos associados em pleno gozo de seus direitos sociais, após solicitação não atendida, comprovadamente, num prazo máximo de 5 (cinco) dias.
"
)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame")
```

What I want:

`data.frames` called by the name of the chapter (like "DO CAPITAL SOCIAL", without the latin numerals) with the ID column and the text.

```r
DOCAPITALSOCIAL <- structure(list(ID = c("56456", "1234564565921"), text = c("
Art. 21 – Texto grande aqui para parecer que tem coisa, deveria ter pego algo de outro lugar para dar esse exemplo", 
"Art. 21 – O Capital Social é ilimitado quanto ao máximo e variável, conforme o número de quotas-partes subscritas, não podendo, porém, o valor ser inferior à R$ 5.000,00 (cinco mil reais).
Parágrafo 1º – O Capital Social é dividido em quotas-partes de R$ 1,00(um real) cada uma, integralizável em duas parcelas de 50% (cinqüenta por cento) cada, em moeda corrente nacional, a primeira no ato da subscrição e a segunda em até um ano após a primeira.
Parágrafo 2º – O associado ao ingressar na cooperativa se obriga a subscrever, 300 (trezentas) quotas-partes.   
"
)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame")
```

I have been trying to do it with `str_extract`, but my regex doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have a lot of text cleansing to do...

A first step to split the chapters in new rows would be splitting at latin numerals:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df %>% separate_rows(text, sep='\\s?[IVX]+\\s')
```

or if you want to get rid of the TÍTULO keyword before the chapter-number:

```
df %>% separate_rows(text, sep='(TÍTULO )?[IVX]+\\s'
```

supposing all chapter numbers are below 40, otherwise you have to add `L` to the regex-pattern.